# how to return every wanted file excluding specific suffix in zsh

Tags: linux, unix, zsh

I want to put target files as input to a command.

My directory currently has mixed **target files** with **weight files**. (*simplified*)

```
(base) directory % ls 
file_015_apple.txt
file_015_orange.txt
file_016_apple.txt
file_016_orange.txt
file_017_apple.txt
file_017_apple.weight.txt
file_017_orange.txt
file_017_orange.weight.txt
...
```

I only want to return target files, but without using grep.
Because it's not readable to the command.

```
ls -l file* | grep -v "weight"
```

I tried many things only to fail.

```
 1044  ls file*.txt ! -name "*weight*"
 1045  ls file*.txt ! -name *weight*
 1046  ls file*.txt ^*weight*
 1049  ls file*(^weight).txt
 1055  ls file*.txt/^*weight.txt
```

If I put all files then an error occurs.

```
% command file_*.txt

*Error*: field_017_apple.weight.weight.txt not found
```

Any solutions?

Comment: What's wrong with `ls *weight*`?

Comment: How about `ls -I "*weight.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ls *~*weight.txt
```

You might need to enable extended glob options:

```
setopt extendedglob
```

Comment: Thanks, but is returns every other files like
'file_017_apple.cat
file_017_apple.xml
file_018_apple.cat
file_018_apple.xml so on...

Comment: OK 
*.txt~*weight.txt
worked for me.
Thanks a lot!